# Index of max element from two lists

Tags: python, numpy

If I have two lists and find the max element between those two lists. 
i'm using the numpy module from python achieve this, assuming `n` and `c` are lists.

```
numpy.max(max(n, c)) --- 1
n = [7,1,54,812,124,6,21]
c = [1,23,5,6,2,345]
final value = [0][3]
```

If the index of an element from a list needs to be obtained, we do something like this:

```
list1.index(int(value))
```

How do we find the index of the maximum element, where this maximum element is obtained as a value from `eq(1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.argmax([5, 4, 3, 9, 1, 2])
3
>>> numpy.argmax([10, 5, 4, 3, 9, 1, 2])
0
```

---

```
import numpy

def find_max_index(xs):
    candidates = [((i,numpy.argmax(x))) for i, x in enumerate(xs)]
    return max(candidates, key=lambda pos: xs[pos[0]][pos[1]])
```

Example:

```
>>> n = [7,1,54,812,124,6,21]
>>> c = [1,23,5,6,2,345]
>>> find_max_index([n, c])
(0, 3)
```

Comment: Does it also work when there are more than two lists?

Comment: @pistal, Could you update the question with actual value of `n` and `c` and what is the expected output?

Comment: Updated.
I don't think it is possible. But, hope is not a bad thing -- Shawshank ;)

Comment: I was also writing a function call to do that :) Thanks! and it looks like your code is much more efficient.

Wait, after the update: You made that god level.